# how to adjust size of bits for frame?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Am using currently program "Recordmydesktop" - which again uses ffmpeg too - for to record some video of desktop-program.

How do I adjust the size in Bytes for the frame ?! - I want to achieve better resolution of the video and then I want to set at least 10 frames per second. - Can I do this from terminal for program "Recordmydesktop" ?! - currently the graphics are "shake,rattle and roll" - thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there are no command line options to specify a region in bytes. All parameters should be in pixels.

From the recordMyDesktop man page :

To specify a region for recording you can type this:

`~$ recordmydesktop -x X_pos -y Y_pos -width WIDTH -height HEIGHT -o foo.ogv`

where X_pos and Y_pos specify the offset in pixels from the upper left
corner of your screen and WIDTH and HEIGHT the size of the window to be recorded(again in pixels).

There is also an option to specify frame rate:

`-fps N(number>0.0)`

```
    Where N is a positive number denoting the desired framerate.
```